# RxJava 2 - how to cancel infinite stream upon error and handle it?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I've got the following infinite stream which does something every second.
What I want is to stop the stream upon error and handle it.
How can I achieve that?

```java
void doSomething() {
        Disposable disposable = execute(doSomethingInner(), 0L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, schedulerProvider.io(), someClass -> 1L).doOnError
                (throwable -> {
            Timber.e(throwable, "error happened");// Never triggered
        })
                .doOnNext(someClass -> Timber.i("doing the infinite stuff"))
                .subscribe(Functions.emptyConsumer(), throwable -> {
                    Timber.e(throwable, "stop doing the infinite stuff");// Never triggered
                });
    }

    Observable<SomeClass> doSomethingInner() {
        return Observable.error(new Exception("something went wrong"));
    }

    Observable<SomeClass> execute(Observable<SomeClass> source,
                                  long delayInterval,
                                  TimeUnit timeUnit,
                                  Scheduler scheduler,
                                  Function<SomeClass, Long> interval) {
        return Observable.defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<SomeClass>>() {
            long currentInterval = delayInterval;

            @Override
            public ObservableSource<SomeClass> call() {
                return Single.timer(currentInterval, timeUnit, scheduler)
                        .flatMapObservable(o -> source)
                        .doOnNext(t -> currentInterval = interval.apply(t));
            }
        })
                .repeat()
                .retry();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `retry()` is consuming your error.
Try to either:

- Remove this `retry()` completely
- or change it to `retry(Predicate<Throwable>)` to decide whether to repeat.

It is default behavior of subscriber to cancel stream on error if you don't consume it earlier, and you should receive callback to `onError()` inside `subscribe()`.